# selecting element with RSpec and JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to select a radio button with JS: true on my rspec test. I don't know how to find the element and select it. Here is my test.

```
within(".plan-picker__plan--best") do
  find("plan_id_3").click
end
```

---

right now it's saying it can't find that element.

---

Here is my HTML

```
    <li class="plan-picker__plan plan-picker__plan--best">
      <div class="plan-picker__plan__header">
        <div class="plan-icon private-eye"></div>
        <h6 class="plan-size">MEDIUM</h6>
        <h5 class="plan-name">Private Eye</h5>
        <p class="plan-summary">Great for small teams that need increased monitoring coverage options on a Project.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="plan-picker__plan__body">
        <ul>
          <li><%= inline_svg("icons.svg", class: "icon icon--pause", href: "#icon-pause") %><strong> 100</strong> Snitches</li>
          <li><%= inline_svg("icons.svg", class: "icon icon--pause", href: "#icon-pause") %> Enhanced Invtervals</li>
          <li><%= inline_svg("icons.svg", class: "icon icon--pause", href: "#icon-pause") %> API</li>
          <li><%= inline_svg("icons.svg", class: "icon icon--pause", href: "#icon-pause") %> Field Agent</li>
          <li><%= inline_svg("icons.svg", class: "icon icon--pause", href: "#icon-pause") %> Integrations</li>
          <li><%= inline_svg("icons.svg", class: "icon icon--pause", href: "#icon-pause") %> Up to <strong>5</strong> team members</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="plan-picker__plan__footer">
        <h4>
          <span class="dollar">$</span>29<span class="period">monthly</span><span class="cents">00</span>
        </h4>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="plan_id" id="plan_id_3" value="3" required data-plan-form-next data-plan-name="Private Eye" data-plan-price="29" />
          <span class="button-big reverse-blue">Select</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </li>
```

---

If you focus on the input. That is what I'm trying to find and select. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Your input is in <div> `plan-picker__plan__footer`. Try looking within that.

Comment: That will get an ambiguous match because I have other elements with that class.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not searching by the ID? The ID should be unique to the page for that very reason.

Comment: I thought I was searching by the ID? I'm trying to find "plan_id_3" which is the ID... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a more general search for anything with "plan_id_3" within a `<li>`. Rspec might not drill down within the `<li>`. Try focusing on the  that contains that ID specifically as

```
within(".plan-picker__plan__footer") do
  find("#plan_id_3").click
end
```

Comment: You're right but I just figured out something else I was doing wrong. `"#plan_id_3"`. I also forgot the #

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that too. But always try to focus on the first upstream container as it makes it more explicit. Why search an entire list when you know it will be in a `div>`?